# Select various text in the same node and put them to different nodes

Tags: xslt

I want to Select various text in the same node and put them to different nodes in XSLT.

Input :

```
<p>The first para
<formula>formula text</formula> The second para 
<list>List text</list>
The third para </p>
```

Desired output :

```
<pcom>The first para</pcom>
<formulai>formula text</formulai>
<pi>The second para</pi>
<listi>List text</listi>
<pi>The third para</pi>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()[preceding-sibling::formula or preceding-sibling::list]">
  <pi><xsl:apply-template/></pi>
</xsl:template>
```

`<p>The first para</p>` , `<p>The second para</p>` and `<p>The third para</p>` are text in same  `<p>`. I want to tarns form them to seperate `<pi>`.

Those text `preceding-sibling` must be `<formula>` or `<list>`. If `preceding-sibling` not a `<formula>` or `<list>` then the output should be in `<pcom>`

How can I solve this? I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for the given example:

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <pcom>
        <xsl:copy/>
    </pcom>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()[preceding-sibling::formula or preceding-sibling::list]">
    <pi>
        <xsl:copy/>
    </pi>
</xsl:template>
```

However, the problem description is ambiguous. If you want to limit the `pi` element to text nodes whose **immediately** preceding sibling is `formula` or `list`, use:

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::formula or self::list]]">
    <pi>
        <xsl:copy/>
    </pi>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()[ following-sibling::*[1][self::list] and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::formula] or preceding-sibling::*[1][self::list]]">
        <pi>
            <xsl:value-of select=" normalize-space(.)"/>
        </pi>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()[following-sibling::*[1][self::formula]]">
        <pcom>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </pcom>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="formula">
        <formulai>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </formulai>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
You may also try this.
```